# date_format() with timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I have in database timestamp but need to add 2 hours to the current timezone.

Here is my code

```
<?= date_format(date_create($new['date_created']), "d/m/Y H:I") ?>
```

and output
`23/08/2022 09:31` need to be `23/08/2022 11:31`

Comment: The documentation for `date_create()` tells you how to do this

Answer (score 1):

`date_create()`, `date_format()`, and most [but not all] other `date_*()` functions are just the procedural interfaces for interacting with DateTime objects. However, there is a *lot* of DateTime functionality that is simply not exposed procedurally, eg: properly modifying the timezone on a DateTime object.

```php
$input = '2022-08-23 13:35:00';

// infer the format. not great, works _most_ of the time, until it doesn't.
$dt = new DateTime($input);

// explicitly specify the format so that it _always_ works
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input);

// wait, what's the timezone? the above leave it out and use the system default, but this is another thing you should specify
$system_tz = new DateTimezone('America/New_York');

// equivalent to the previous, but with timezones
$dt = new DateTime($input, $system_tz);
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input, $system_tz);

printf("System date: %s\n", $dt->format("d/m/Y H:i"));
printf("System date: %s\n", $dt->format("c"));

// now to modify it to somewhere else
$user_tz = new DateTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
$dt->setTimezone($user_tz);

printf("\n");
printf("  User date: %s\n", $dt->format("d/m/Y H:i"));
printf("  User date: %s\n", $dt->format("c"));
```

Output:

```
System date: 23/08/2022 13:35
System date: 2022-08-23T13:35:00-04:00

  User date: 23/08/2022 10:35
  User date: 2022-08-23T10:35:00-07:00
```

Put succintly:

```php
$input = '2022-08-23 13:35:00';
$system_tz = new DateTimezone('America/New_York');
$user_tz = new DateTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
$date_str = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input, $system_tz)
    ->setTimezone($user_tz)
    ->format("d/m/Y H:i");
```

It is especially important that you do not treat timezone conversions as simply plus/minus a number of hours as the rules that govern timezones across various localities can be *wildly* granular and inconsistent. Always use available date library functions.

Ref:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

You can select your server's **dateTimeZone** and use **DateInterval** to add the amount of time you want.

example:

```
 $hoursDB = date_format(date_create($new['date_created']), "d/m/Y H:I");
 $now = new DateTime($hoursDB); 
 $now->add(new DateInterval('PT2H')); // add 2 hours
 $dateTimeNew = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

outPut 2022-08-24 04:32:45

Links:
DateTime : https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime
DateInterval : https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: You are mixing both the the procedural and OOP forms of interacting with DateTime objects, needlessly formatting the time back to a string just to re-interpolate it on the next line, and then never actually touching the timezone functionality provided by DateTime.

Comment: h yes, thanks for your remarks of my code. @Sammitch